# How to write the syntax of CONCAT with + operator in SQL to combine strings in a column and strings in another column?

Tags: sql, string, function, syntax, concatenation

## How to combine two strings in two columns using CONCAT with the + operator?

It was shown error when I typed

SELECT

start_name + end_name

......

....

in SQL . Here, start_*name and end*_name  are column headers.

I expected each string in each row to get combined with the corresponding strings in the other row.

Comment: Which database do you use?

Comment: Simply use the double pipe ```||``` sign to combine the two rows output as follows: ```SELECT COLUMN_A || ' ' || COLUMN_B```

Comment: Which DB do you use and what is the error msg? [ select start_name + end_name from table_name ] should work in most cases.

Comment: Should fail in most cases...

Comment: "_each string in each row to get combined with the corresponding strings in the other row_"? Do you mean you want to combine vales from different row? Show us some sample table data _and the expected result_ - all as formatted text (no pictures, no links.) I.e. a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

What is the error you get? Tested fine.
Using isnull() to handle potential null in the fields.

```
-- Preparing a #temp table with 2 string columns
select 'String A' as row1, 'String B' as row2 into #temp

-- Combing 2 columns
select isnull(row1,'') + isnull(row2,'') from #temp
```